# Finder does not open

Tags: finder, dock

Clicking on the finder icon in the dock has no effect. To open the finder I have to open the context menu and choose "New Window".

I already stoped the finder process, without success.

How can I fix that?

Comment: what is not showing, the side bar or nothing.

Comment: Nothing. I have to go via the context menu every time.

Comment: Have you checked output in the console.app ?

Comment: @maseth Check for what?

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried simply clicking on the Finder icon in the dock ?

That always works for me.

I would delete my Finder .plist

I would also "zap my PRAM"

Comment: Please reread the first sentence of the question :-) also it would help to know where the finder.plist is stored and how zapping a PRAM works.

Comment: Thank you for your effort, please read the question first.